# nppiFilter breaks output image

Tags: cuda, nvidia, npp

I wrote an example of BoxFilter using NPP, but the output image looks broken. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <ImagesCPU.h>
#include <ImagesNPP.h>
#include <Exceptions.h>

#include <npp.h>
#include "utils.h"


void boxfilter1_transform( Npp8u *data, int width, int height ){
    size_t size = width * height * 4;

    // declare a host image object for an 8-bit RGBA image
    npp::ImageCPU_8u_C4 oHostSrc(width, height);

    Npp8u *nDstData = oHostSrc.data();
    memcpy(nDstData, data, size * sizeof(Npp8u));

    // declare a device image and copy construct from the host image,
    // i.e. upload host to device
    npp::ImageNPP_8u_C4 oDeviceSrc(oHostSrc);

    // create struct with box-filter mask size
    NppiSize oMaskSize = {3, 3};

    // Allocate memory for pKernel
    Npp32s hostKernel[9] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    Npp32s *pKernel;

    checkCudaErrors( cudaMalloc((void**)&pKernel, oMaskSize.width * oMaskSize.height * sizeof(Npp32s)) );
    checkCudaErrors( cudaMemcpy(pKernel, hostKernel, oMaskSize.width * oMaskSize.height * sizeof(Npp32s),
                                cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

    Npp32s nDivisor = 9;

    // create struct with ROI size given the current mask
    NppiSize oSizeROI = {oDeviceSrc.width() - oMaskSize.width + 1, oDeviceSrc.height() - oMaskSize.height + 1};
    // allocate device image of appropriatedly reduced size
    npp::ImageNPP_8u_C4 oDeviceDst(oSizeROI.width, oSizeROI.height);
    // set anchor point inside the mask
    NppiPoint oAnchor = {2, 2};

    // run box filter
    NppStatus eStatusNPP;
    eStatusNPP = nppiFilter_8u_C4R(oDeviceSrc.data(), oDeviceSrc.pitch(),
                                   oDeviceDst.data(), oDeviceDst.pitch(),
                                   oSizeROI, pKernel, oMaskSize, oAnchor, nDivisor);
    //printf("NppiFilter error status %d\n", eStatusNPP);
    NPP_DEBUG_ASSERT(NPP_NO_ERROR == eStatusNPP);

    // declare a host image for the result
    npp::ImageCPU_8u_C4 oHostDst(oDeviceDst.size());
    // and copy the device result data into it
    oDeviceDst.copyTo(oHostDst.data(), oHostDst.pitch());
    memcpy(data, oHostDst.data(), size * sizeof(Npp8u));

    return;
}
```

Most part of code was copied from example boxFilterNPP.cpp. And the output image: http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/7716/o8z.png

Why it can be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a striding problem.  Change this line:

```
npp::ImageCPU_8u_C4 oHostDst(oDeviceDst.size());
```

To this:

```
npp::ImageCPU_8u_C4 oHostDst(oDeviceSrc.size());
```

What is happening?

Let's assume your input image is 600x450.

- `oHostSrc` is 600 x 450, and the pitch is 600x4 = 2400.
- the `memcpy` from `data` to `oHostSrc` is ok because they have the same width and pitch.
- `oDeviceSrc` picks up the size from `oHostSrcc` (600x450)
- `oDeviceDst` is *slightly smaller* than `oDeviceSrc`, because it only picks up the size of the ROI, so it is something like 596x446.
- Your code was creating `oHostDst` to be the same size as `oDeviceDst`, so about 596x446.
- The `.copyTo` operation copies the oDeviceDst (pitched) 596x446 image to (unpitched) `oHostDst`, also 596x446.
- The final `memcpy` breaks the image, because it is copying a 596x446 `oHostDst` image to a 600x450 `data` region.

The solution is to create `oHostDst` at 600x450 and let the `.copyTo` operation handle the difference in line sizes and pitches.

The original code didn't have this problem because there were *no* unpitched copies anywhere in that code (e.g. no use of raw `memcpy`).  As long as you handle the source and destination pitch and width explicitly at every copy step, it does not matter whether you create the final image as 600x450 or 596x446.  But your final `memcpy` operation was not handling pitch and width explicitly, instead it implicitly assumed both source and destination were of the same size, and this was not the case.

Comment: thank you for the helping! The problem solved! After I've changed the line (like in your answer) the output image became like original. Than I changed: `npp::ImageCPU_8u_C4 oHostDst(oDeviceSrc.size());` to: `npp::ImageCPU_8u_C4 oHostDst(width, height);` and my filter makes its job correctly!